# Order dataviews on different columns and paging with Sharepoint 2007

Tags: data-view-web-part, 2007, ordering, paging

Is it possible to order a paged dataview on different columns (using a query string parameter)?
Sharepoint 2007.

Answer (score 1):

This blogpost should get you up and running:

http://sympmarc.com/2008/12/16/sorting-displays-in-data-view-web-parts/

Let me know if you have specific questions with this.